# Filter users by fullname in configureDatagridFilters

Tags: symfony-2.3, sonata-user-bundle

I'm trying to filter the user list with de getFullname() method, with no result.

```
$filterMapper                
            ->add('fullname', null, array('label' => 'Full name'))
```

FileTypeGuesser don't find the property 'fullname'.

Answer (score 0):

its resolves using callback

```
->add('NombreCompleto', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
                'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                    if (!$value || $value['value'] == '') {
                        return;
                    }
                    $queryBuilder->andWhere('CONCAT(' . $alias . '.firstname, CONCAT(\' \', ' . $alias . '.lastname)) LIKE :term')->setParameter(':term', '%' . $value['value'] . '%');
                    return true;
                },
                'field_type' => 'text'
            ))
```